# Can't access WildFly over HTTPS with browsers but can with OpenSSL client

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, https, openssl, wildfly

I've deployed Keycloak on WildFly 10 via Docker. SSL support was enabled via cli. Final `standalone.xml` has:

```
<security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
  <server-identities>
      <ssl>
        <keystore path="keycloak.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="changeit"
 alias="mydomain" key-password="changeit"/>
      </ssl>
   </server-identities>
 </security-realm>
```

Undertow subsystem:

```
<https-listener name="default-https" security-realm="UndertowRealm"
 socket-binding="https"/>
```

Key was generated and placed in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration

```
keytool -genkey -noprompt -alias mydomain -dname "CN=mydomain,
 OU=mydomain, O=mydomain, L=none, S=none, C=SI" -keystore
 keycloak.jks -storepass changeit -keypass changeit
```

Port 8443 is exposed via Docker.

Accessing `https://mydomain:8443/` in chrome results in `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`. Firefox returns *"Secure Connection Failed, the connection was interrupted..."*

However, OpenSSL client works nicely:

```
 openssl s_client -connect mydomain:8443
```

Input:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: https://mydomain:8443
```

This returns the Keycloak welcome page.

So clearly WildFly is working but I am being blocked by the browsers for whatever reason. What could this reason be? I was under the impression that I should be able to add an exception for self signed certificate in either browser. Maybe the generated key length is too short or maybe I am hitting some other security constraint imposed by Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: I always get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
created the jks and made above changes. Can't understand what might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using these parameters in keytool solved the problem: `-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048`

Answer (score 0):

> ... `-dname "CN=mydomain`

The certificate is probably malformed. The Browsers and other user agents, like cURL and OpenSSL, use different policies to validate a end-entity certificate. The browser will reject a certificate if the hostname is in the *Common Name (CN)*, while other user agents will accept it.

The short answer to *this* problem is, place DNS names in the *Subject Alternate Name (SAN)*, and not the *Common Name (CN)*.

You may still encounter other problems, but getting the names right will help immensely with browsers.

---

> However, OpenSSL client works nicely:
>       `openssl s_client -connect mydomain:8443`

OpenSSL *prior to* 1.1.0 did ***not*** perform hostname validation. Prior version will accept any name.

cURL or Wget would be a better tool to test with in this case.

---

For reading on the verification you should perform when using OpenSSL, see:

- [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client)

For reading on the rules for hostnames and where they should appear in a X509 certificate, see:

- [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639)
- [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639)